# change selected value of dropdown on change of model value in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this dropdown which is dynamic

```
  <select [name]="data.nameLabel" class="form-control height-reset placholder-text "
                                           [(ngModel)]="selDropdown[data.sno]"
                                            (change)="Selected(data.sno,selDropdown[data.sno])">
                                            <option *ngFor="let opt of dropdown" [ngValue]="opt">
                                                {{opt}}</option>
                                        </select>
```

this dropdown contains yes and no value on change of value i want to set No on some condition

```
Selected()
{
..

 this.selDropdown[id] = "No";
}
```

changing the modal value and it's value is changed but dropdown selected value is still old one.

Comment: Create a functional example for us in stackblitz for better understanding.